# Smaller element inside div HTML

Tags: html, css

I have many images inside my div where I position them so that all are complete each other’s.
Also I need that when I copy the div to other page the images sty the same but I can modife where to put the div in my page 
Now my problem is:
I want these entires images inside the div to be smaller and still are complete each other 
Example of My code:

```
    <div style="position:absolute; top:900px; left:500px" >
      <img id="Burimi" style="position:absolute; left:10px" src="Images/Reagion/Burimi-B.png"/>
        <img id=""  style="position:relative; left:98px;top:1px;" src="Images/Reagion/N Batinah-B.png" />

      </div>
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: Upload your `Burimi` and `Batinah-B` images.

Comment: Don't do this, use an SVG map instead. It will scale perfectly and it's more suited for the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resize the container and not the images. For example you can use the following for the parent `div`:

```
div {
transform: scale(.5,.5); /*Half width and height */
-ms-transform: scale(.5,.5); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: scale(.5,.5); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: scale(.5,.5); /* Opera */
-moz-transform: scale(.5,.5); /* Firefox */
}
```

Comment: so if i do that , all image will re-size too?

Comment: exactly! everything inside your parent `div` will stay at the same position and will resize as one object.

Comment: Oky that's seems what I want (am beginner).BUT where to post this code in css file ? and then if so it will not affect other div ?

Comment: you need to add an `id` for your parent `div` and target it with your css. For example your `div` should be like: `<div id="mymap">your images here</div>` and your css: `div#mymap{css properties here}`. This will only affect the `div` you want.

Comment: If you want to place your css inline then your `html` should be: `<div style="position:absolute; top:900px; left:500px;transform: scale(.5,.5);-ms-transform: scale(.5,.5);-webkit-transform: scale(.5,.5);-o-transform: scale(.5,.5);-moz-transform: scale(.5,.5);" >`

Comment: Thank you very much :) WORK FINE.What about moving this div any where is oky ? i think i have only to move it base on top left right ?

Comment: You can move your `div` by changing the `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left` values but I recommend that you avoid `absolute` positioning and instead place it in a semantically correct position in your html.

Comment: oky got that.ONE more question: u can see that I am defined the top left for the image and i do that by trying different px every time until i got my images in correct place. There no other way that I can do it manually and get the px , because these hard ? i wish u understand what i meant.

Comment: Set you parent `div` in `relative` position and your images in `absolute` position with the coordinates you desire. I'm just telling you to avoid positioning your parent `div` with `absolute` position.

Comment: Yah, I got that already .Is there a way to defined the coordinates? because normally i assume them and try many of them  until i get the  suitable one .

Comment: not really.. in your case "try and error" is the only approach

Comment: OMG I could not understand why there is no software which dose this!this problem i always face.may be we have to make one .

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'd be better using an [`image map`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.6). Have one image containing all the images as you'd expect them to be displayed on the page, then use `areas` to differentiate between the different regions on the image.

Comment: yah i know that recently but the beauty of image button that u can change src when mouseover.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:relative` in the `div`, and `position:absolute` for all the images.

This way you can put the div anywhere and the images Will always be positioned relatively to the `div`

Comment: I use for all of them div and image :absolute , and then i did as u said .. but i could not see and different?

Comment: You should stop for a second, and understand how position works. And you are not using absolute for all of them, because the second image is relatively positioned.

Comment: Oky i think u meant to have div as absolute and all other elements inside as relative ..so all image position according to the pixel of div. right ?